# Convert module from 1.5 to 2.5 version

Tags: joomla, module, migrate

Have been Googling for hours to find the solution on how to convert my modules from Joomla version 1.5 to 2.5.

The modules doesn't show up in the administrator area under "Extensions > Module Manager".

Where should I start and how should I do to migrate my modules?

Comment: You can try this-http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6

Comment: Just to get it clear (little bit confusied by this). Module is a type of extension?

Comment: Yes it is.Most probably your module xml may have some problem.Try to change it as the new version like install->extension and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Updating fairly simple modules to be 2.5 compatible is very simple. The first thing you start with is the XML file.

`<install version="1.5">` needs to be replaced with `<extension version="2.5">`

The same goes for the tag at the very end: `</install>` to `</extension>`

Then, you will need to start with the parameters. Each parameter is defined with `<param>` and needs to be changed to `<field>`. However a little more needs to be added to the beginning and end of the fields as shown below:

Updating fairly simple modules to be 2.5 compatible is very simple. The first thing you start with is the XML file.

`<install version="1.5">` needs to be replaced with `<extension version="2.5">`

The same goes for the tag at the very end: `</install>` to `</extension>`

Then, you will need to start with the parameters. Each parameter is defined with `<param>` and needs to be changed to `<field>`. However a little more needs to be added to the beginning and end of the fields as shown below:

```
<config>
   <fields name="params">
      <fieldset name="basic">
            //Fields go in here
      </fieldset>
   </fields>
</config>
```

Also, if you are using language files, you will need to copy and paste the following one you have and add `.sys` into the name like so `en-GB.mod_example.sys.ini`. Then open this file and ensure that the description of the module is the only translation in the file. Once done, specify the language file in the XML. Don't forget that language file's for Joomla 2.5 don't support `#` at the beginning of the data lines, and will need to be replaced with `;`

It might also be an idea to keep up to date with any functions that are removed or deprecated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What to do if we need to convert it from 1.5 to 3.5 Can you please refer me to documentation or guide a bit?

Comment: There's no documentation snippet I know of that shows you how to migrate a module from 1.5 to 3.x....have a look at the current documenation for Joomla modules and also look at some of the core modules to see how they're written.

Answer (score 0):

Modules, Components and Plugins are all extensions, with [different purposes.](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29)

As mentioned by @Irfan already check the Joomla! Documentation pages:

[Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6)

[Joomla! Manifest files](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files)

As mentioned before it may work just by updating the manifest file (xml file) for the module. If it's a component things can get more complicated.

As a side-note, the more vague are about your problem, the more vague will the answers be. Get back to us with more details (like component name or errors that you get).